# How do I make a webpage scroll from the bottom?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to start a webpages scroll from the bottom, I have gotten it working with this little snippet of code

```
$('a#bottom').trigger('click')
```

where `a#bottom` is an anchor to the bottom of the page. Is there a better way than using the trigger.

I would like the page to always load at the bottom... is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set a redirect like:

`location.href = <thecurrenturl>+"#bottom"`

But it doesn't differ much from your method. Anchors are best since adjusting scroll amounts isn't the same across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can include the bookmark when you load the page, e.g. `SomePage.html#bottom`. That will make the browser jump to the bookmark when the page loads.